# python RNN LSTM error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, lstm

This is a recurrent neural network LSTM model meant to predict the future values of forex market movement.

The data set shape is (1713, 50), the first column is the Date time index and the others are numeric values.
but right after printing the Training data and Validation data shapes the error start.

When I tried to implement this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Business\Stocks\StocksDF.csv", parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0], low_memory=False, dtype='object')
features = len(df.columns)
val_ratio = 0.2
epochs = 500
batch_size = df.__len__()
sequence_length = 822

data = df.as_matrix()
data_processed = []
for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
    data_processed.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])
data_processed = np.array(data_processed)

val_split = round((1 - val_ratio) * data_processed.shape[0])
train = data_processed[:, int(val_split), :]
val = data_processed[int(val_split):, :]

print('Training data: {}'.format(train.shape))
print('Validation data: {}'.format(val.shape))



train_samples, train_nx, train_ny = train.shape
val_samples, val_nx, val_ny = val.shape

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx * train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx * val_ny))

preprocessor = MinMaxScaler().fit(train)
train = preprocessor.transform(train)
val = preprocessor.transform(val)

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx, train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx, val_ny))

X_train = train[:, : -1]
y_train = train[:, -1][:, -1]
X_val = val[:, : -1]
y_val = val[:, -1][:, -1]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], features))
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], X_val.shape[1], features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), units=100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'mse', 'accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=2)

preds_val = model.predict(X_val)
diff = []
for i in range(len(y_val)):
    pred = preds_val[i][0]
    diff.append(y_val[i] - pred)

real_min = preprocessor.data_min_[104]
real_max = preprocessor.data_max_[104]
print(preprocessor.data_min_[:1])
print(preprocessor.data_max_[:1])

preds_real = preds_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min
y_val_real = y_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min

plt.plot(preds_real, label='Predictions')
plt.plot(y_val_real, label='Actual values')
plt.xlabel('test')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
print(model.summary())
```

I got this error:

Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):

Training data: (891, 50)

File "E:/Tutorial/new.py", line 31, in 
Validation data: (178, 822, 50)

train_samples, train_nx, train_ny = train.shape

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: if I can see right the problem starts before that if you can see the training data has 2 values while the validation data has 3 values. as same as the error

Comment: @roganjosh any suggestion

Comment: At a _guess_, `train_nx, train_ny = train.shape`. But I could be well off on what is returned. The point being, the error message is standard across all of python and so all the code and backstory is irrelevant, the only thing you need to understand is what `train.shape` actually represents.

Comment: Try `print(train.shape)` and see what it looks like.

Comment: i did try to print(train.shape) and i got the very same error i think mr hanx is right

Comment: `print(train.shape)` gave you the same error? I can't see how that's possible. I'm not suggesting that `print` would fix the problem, simply to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in this line:

```
train = data_processed[:, int(val_split), :]
```

It should be:

```
train = data_processed[:int(val_split), :, :]
val = data_processed[int(val_split):, :, :]
```